# What spider is this? Found in Hawaii

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I found this spider at the edge of a park in Hawaii. ~1cm in length. The area I found it was very dry and had thick tall grasses just a few feet away.

[image]

Comment: Looks to be an araneid ([orb weaver spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orb-weaver_spider)).

Comment: You have a Spotted Orbweaver (genus Neoscona). Likely either a Western Spotted Orbweaver (N. oaxacensis) or Red-femured Spotted Orbweaver (N. domiciliorum)